# Rails: how can I pluck a scoped ActiveRecord association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model with a scoped association:

```
has_many :locations, -> {
  where(['tags.type = ?', LocationTag.name])   
}, through: :person_taggings, source: :tag
```

I'd like to pluck it, like this `Person.pluck(:location)`, but I realise that doesn't work.

What code would let me achieve the same result as plucking?

Comment: `pluck` is used to retrieve results from one column's rows into an array. I'm not sure what do you expect what `Person.pluck(:location)` should return.

Comment: The locations scope returns the associated LocationTag models for a record. I'd like a Person.pluck(:location) equivalent to return all of the LocationTags associated with all people.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pluck` only to fetch relation column values. To achieve what you want do:

```
Location.joins(:people).group("#{Location.table_name}.id")
```